# Query with the window function FIRST_VALUE produces duplicates

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

#### Setup

My tables are like this:

```
CREATE TABLE challenges (
  id uuid,
  user_id uuid,
  fe_challenge_id uuid,
  status_type varchar(50),
  created_at timestamp,
  updated_at timestamp
);
```

This table stores users' attempted challenges. `status_type` can be `Ended` or `Paused`. User can attempt any challenge more than once, but the condition is any new same challenge won't be logged before the previous one is ended.

```
CREATE TABLE timelogs (
  id uuid,
  challenge_id uuid,
  start_time timestamp,
  end_time timestamp,
  created_at timestamp,
  updated_at timestamp
  );
```

This table stores the users' logs for their challenges, when user opens challenge screen, entry is made in this table with `start_time` and when closes the screen, entry is updated with `end_time`. This way we counts sessions and total time of a specific challenge attempted by user. The number of entries of logs as a session and all of their time is calculated via start and end time.

```
CREATE TABLE scripts (
  id uuid,
  user_id uuid,
  challenge_id uuid,
  script integer,
  timestamp timestamp,
  created_at timestamp,
  updated_at timestamp
  );
```

This table stores scripts read by a user in a challenge. i.e. in a challenge, there can be hundreds of scripts.

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/22hyJ3FF9sakaJadcYDxmt/3) with sample data.

#### Task

I want to fetch challenges counting its sessions and total time spent on a challenge by a user and with script no which is the first and last for a challenge.
The twist is, query must not return a challenge ended multiple i.e. if user has completed `challenge A` 5 times, and sixth one is in progress, then the query should return one log for Ended (the latest one) and one which is in progress.

Here is the query I'm using to fetch the records:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FIRST_VALUE(c.id) OVER w id,
    FIRST_VALUE(c.user_id) OVER w user_id,
    FIRST_VALUE(c.fe_challenge_id) OVER w fe_challenge_id,
    FIRST_VALUE(c.status_type) OVER w status_type,
    FIRST_VALUE(c.created_at) OVER w created_at,
    FIRST_VALUE(c.updated_at) OVER w updated_at,
    FIRST_VALUE(r.script) OVER wr last_script,
    FIRST_VALUE(r.script) OVER fr first_script
FROM
    challenges as c,
    scripts as r
WHERE
    c.user_id='cc21564f-17ce-4d63-8447-ac3e2d69a3e4' 
    and c.status_type != 'Incomplete' 
    and c.status_type != 'Null' 
    and c.id = r.challenge_id
WINDOW w as (
        PARTITION BY c.user_id, c.fe_challenge_id, c.status_type
        ORDER BY c.updated_at desc
    ),
    wr as (
        PARTITION BY r.challenge_id
        ORDER BY r."timestamp" DESC
    ),
    fr as (
        PARTITION BY r.challenge_id
        ORDER BY r."timestamp" ASC
    );
```

This query returns accurate data like in below image:

[image]

But when I try to fetch timestamp from script table or calculate the sessions or time from timelog table, it creates duplication. i.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FIRST_VALUE(c.id) OVER w id,
    FIRST_VALUE(c.user_id) OVER w user_id,
    FIRST_VALUE(c.fe_challenge_id) OVER w fe_challenge_id,
    FIRST_VALUE(c.status_type) OVER w status_type,
    FIRST_VALUE(c.star_amount) OVER w star_amount,
    FIRST_VALUE(c.created_at) OVER w created_at,
    FIRST_VALUE(c.updated_at) OVER w updated_at,
    FIRST_VALUE(r.script) OVER wr last_script,
    FIRST_VALUE(r.script) OVER fr first_script,
    FIRST_VALUE(r."timestamp") OVER wr last_script_time, ---This line
    (SELECT count(id) from timelogs where challenge_id=c.id) as sessions, --- This line
    (SELECT sum(extract(epoch from (end_time::timestamp - start_time::timestamp))) from timelogs where challenge_id=c.id) as timer ---This line
FROM
    challenges as c,
    scripts as r
WHERE
    c.user_id='cc21564f-17ce-4d63-8447-ac3e2d69a3e4' 
    and c.status_type != 'Incomplete' 
    and c.status_type != 'Null' 
    and c.id = r.challenge_id
WINDOW w as (
        PARTITION BY c.user_id, c.fe_challenge_id, c.status_type
        ORDER BY c.updated_at desc
    ),
    wr as (
        PARTITION BY r.challenge_id
        ORDER BY r."timestamp" DESC
    ),
    fr as (
        PARTITION BY r.challenge_id
        ORDER BY r."timestamp" ASC
    );
```

The result is below:

[image]

You will notice that the number of records is also increased from 29 to 34 and the two highlight records are duplicated with different values.

If I missed something, please ask for it.

Why do I get duplicates? Is there a better approach?

Comment: What do you expect the end result to look like when there are a different number of `sessions` for each `id`? Your join by `id` in the `sessions` subquery is not on the `FIRST_VALUE(id)` but rather it'll join to every `id` in the table instead. If you want it to join by the `FIRST_VALUE(id)` then you'd need to wrap  your entire query in a CTE or subquery, and then join to it to get the `sessions`.

Comment: How do i do that, sorry I could not get you. @J.D.

Comment: "*What do you expect the end result to look like?...*" - Please update your post with an example and I'll be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in question is that the added correlated subqueries make previously identical rows distinct. And `DISTINCT` is applied *after* computing the whole `SELECT` list. So you end up with "duplicates".

Move your original query into subquery, and compute the additional columns in a `LATERAL` subquery *after* applying `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (

   -- your original query here

   ) c
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT count(id) AS sessions
        , sum(extract(epoch FROM end_time - start_time)) AS timer
   FROM   timelogs
   WHERE  challenge_id = c.id
   ) t;
```

Computing `sessions` and `timer` in a single subquery is cheaper.

About the sequence of events in a `SELECT` query:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8242764/939860)

About lateral subqueries:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

Comment: Your whole query is hugely inefficient to begin with. Cleaning up is a job for a paid contractor, not fit for a *question* here.

Comment: Thanks... I got the results by modifying query like yours, removing timelogs subquery from main,
But it is still duplicating the records.. if the timestamp column from scripts is removed from the main query, then all the records are exact and result is fine. if you can look at the fiddle I shared... and try runing your query, you will get the idea of duplicating records.
And I do know that my query is not that much efficient, I am trying on it. Thanks.

Comment: @RafiAbro: The same issue applies to the timestamp column from `scripts` Adding it to the row makes previously identical rows distinct. Define *which* timestamp to add per group (first, last?) and add only that (later).

Comment: the last one, as I am trying to fetch last script number with it's timestamp.